# I do not understand how execlp() works in Linux

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have spent the last 2 days trying to understand the `execlp()` system call, but yet here I am. Let me get straight to the issue.

The `man page` of execlp declares the system call as `int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);` with the description: *The const char arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(), and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.*

Yet I see the system call being called like this in our text book: `execlp(“/bin/sh”, ..., “ls -l /bin/??”, ...);` (the "..." are for us to figure out as students). However this system call doesn´t even resemble anything like the declaration on the `man page` of the system call.

I am super confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: because in the man page it's the definition of the function and I guess in your text book it's an exemple of how to use it

Comment: You are right. But what exactly is it trying to do in the above example and how exactly is it being used? Google has very poor info I feel on execlp().

Comment: What do you mean it "doesn't even resemble" the declaration?  The arguments are `char *`.  That very closely resembles a `char *`!

Answer (score 107, accepted):

this prototype:

```
  int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
```

Says that execlp ìs a variable argument function. It takes 2 `const char *`. The rest of the arguments, if any,  are the additional arguments to hand over to program we want to run - also `char *` - all these are C strings (and the last argument must be a NULL pointer)

So, the `file` argument is the path name of an executable file to be executed. `arg` is the string we want to appear as `argv[0]` in the executable. By convention, `argv[0]` is just the file name of the executable, normally it's set to the same as `file`.

The `...` are now the additional arguments to give to the executable.

Say you run this from a commandline/shell:

```
$ ls
```

That'd be `execlp("ls", "ls", (char *)NULL);`
Or if you run

```
$ ls -l /
```

That'd be `execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", "/", (char *)NULL);`

So on to `execlp("/bin/sh", ..., "ls -l /bin/??", ...);`

Here you are going to the shell, /bin/sh , and you're giving the shell a command to execute. That command is "ls -l /bin/??". You can run that manually from a commandline/shell:

```
 $ ls -l /bin/??
```

Now, how do you run a shell and tell it to execute a command ? You open up the documentation/man page for your shell and read it.

What you want to run is:

```
$ /bin/sh -c "ls -l /bin/??"
```

This becomes

```
  execlp("/bin/sh","/bin/sh", "-c", "ls -l /bin/??", (char *)NULL);
```

Side note:
The `/bin/??` is doing pattern matching, this pattern matching is done by the shell, and it expands to all files under /bin/ with 2 characters. If you simply did

```
  execlp("ls","ls", "-l", "/bin/??", (char *)NULL);
```

Probably nothing would happen (unless there's a file actually named `/bin/??`) as there's no shell that interprets and expands /bin/??

Comment: Are there any special header files you need to run shell commands like this? I tried the above examples and I recieved a bunch of errors like `error: stray ‘\235’ in program` and `error: too few arguments to function ‘execlp’`. Im guessing its because of a header file missing. I used the function like this: `execlp(“/bin/sh”,“/bin/sh”, "-c", mystring, (char *)NULL);` where mystring is a string varible containing an input string of whatever bash command I want `execlp()` to execute.

Comment: @ArmanIqbal The quotes somehow got changed here. But this is C code, so change the strings to be enclosed in double quotes. These: `"` Also read the man page for [execlp](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) to learn which header files you need to include

Answer (score 19):

The limitation of execl is that when executing a shell command or any other script that is not in the current working directory, then we have to pass the full path of the command or the script. 
Example:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-la", NULL);
```

*The workaround to passing the full path of the executable is to use the function **execlp***, that searches for the file (1st argument of execlp) in those directories pointed by PATH:

```
execlp("ls", "ls", "-la", NULL);
```

Comment: will it work if i use execl("/bin", "ls", "-la", NULL);  only mentioning directory name instead of full path of file.

Comment: @pankajkushwaha: No, the first argument must point to the executable file you want to execute

Comment: You don't necessarily have to pass the full path; for example you can pass `../bin/some_command`.