# use exec in c program

Tags: c, linux, command, exec

I am using linux and I want to write a program in c that reads commands from user until I enter stop.For each command the main program will create a process A which will create another process B.The process B will execute the command entered by user.I want to make it work using exec but it only works for one word commands (ex:`pwd` , `ls`) , if i enter for example `ls -l` it says that there is no such file or directory.The code i wrote so far :

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 100

int main() {
    char input[N];
    scanf(" %[^\n]s",input); //reads from user inputs that can include space 
    while (strcmp(input,"stop") != 0) { // verifies if entered command == stop
        int a;
        a = fork();//creates the process A
        if (a == -1) {
            perror("fork imposibil!");
            exit(1);
        }
        if (a == 0) {
            printf("a\n");//i printed that to verify if my fork works
            int b;

            b = fork();//creates process B
            if (b == -1) {
                perror("fork imposibil!");
                exit(1);
            }
            if (b == 0) { // the part that makes me problems , i try to use exec to execute the command that is stored in input
                printf("b\n");
                if (execlp(input,"",(char*) 0) < 0) {
                    perror("Error exec");
                    exit(0);
                }
                exit(0);
            }
            wait(0);
            exit(0);
        }
        wait(0);

        scanf(" %[^\n]s",input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone help me please ?
P.S. I don't think that my code was so impossible to read but i hope it's better now

Comment: First of all learn how to write readable code, and then you might ask a question, because reading your code as it was, was almost imposible. For example, i didn't see the `exit()` after `perror()`, didn't see it at all, and I thought, Oops, he reports the errors, but still ignores them. And I think you should call `_exit(0)` instead of `exit(0)` from the child process.

Answer (score 2):

From your example `ls -l`, the `-l` should be passed to the argument.

```
int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
```

The citation from the [help](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) says

> The function can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn. Together they
>   describe a list of one or more pointers to null-terminated strings
>   that represent the argument list available to the executed program.
>   **The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename
>   associated with the file being executed**. The list of arguments must be
>   terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions,
>   this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing arguments to the function execlp() the way it expects them to be.

> The initial argument for these functions is the name of a file that is
>   to be executed.
>
> The const char *arg and subsequent ellipses in the execl(), execlp(),
>   and execle() functions can be thought of as arg0, arg1, ..., argn.
>   Together they describe a list of one or more pointers to
>   null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to
>   the executed program. The first argument, by convention, should point
>   to the filename associated with the file being executed. The list of
>   arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are
>   variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.

Have a look at this explanation on how to use execlp() function-
[I do not understand how execlp() works in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558937/i-do-not-understand-how-execlp-work-in-linux)

I guess you would have to use a string splitter function with a delimiter `" "` to get the command line arguments like `-l` in your case `ls -l`.

`strtok()` provides this functionality in C.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[] = "A bird came down the walk";
    printf("Parsing the input string '%s'\n", input);
    char *token = strtok(input, " ");
    while(token) {
        puts(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }

    printf("Contents of the input string now: '");
    for(size_t n = 0; n < sizeof input; ++n)
        input[n] ? printf("%c", input[n]) : printf("\\0");
    puts("'");
}
```