# How to get 'ls -l $pwd' working using execlp?

Tags: c, linux, exec

I have read the following answer from [@nos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21559499/2439234) on how to implement the execlp command but I am unable to run the same specifically for `ls -l $pwd` using execlp. I have tried both 
`execlp("ls","ls", "-l", "$pwd", (char *)NULL);` and 
`execlp("ls","ls", "-l", "pwd", (char *)NULL);` but nothing seems to work. Any directions in this thought process would be really helpful

Thanks.

Comment: You need to call `getenv` if you want to use an environment variable in a C program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `$...` variable belongs to `shell`, *not* the OS internal. When in shell you type such variables, shell will transform them to their actual value and then call system call.

In C program, you need to do it by yourself:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    char *cwd = getcwd(NULL, 0);
    execlp("ls","ls", "-l", cwd, (char *)NULL);
}
```

[`getcwd()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html) will give you the current directory.