# execlp function with user input C language

Tags: c

I am trying to write code that takes user input and passes this input to the execlp function.

Right now I am working with the scenario that the user will type 'ls -pla' as a way to familiarize myself with the process before adding additional features.  To shorten my code, I omitted the loops to initialize the PATH variable.  To simplify the below code, I just initialized the PATH variable with "ls" for this example.  The code behaves the same way either way.

I use the fgets() function to get the user input and write it to an array called buf.  I then change the last character of the array from a newline to a null terminator.

I then use an array of pointers to strings called args.  I initialize the args[0] to the PATH array and args[1] to the buf array.

When I pass args[0] and args[1] to execlp, the function appears to read args[0] just fine.  But it is not reading args[1].

I left comments in the below code to show my thought processes.  Basically I want to get the remaining user input read by the function, but my approach isn't working.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
char buf[500];
char* args[250];
char PATH[2] = "ls";

memset(buf, '\0', sizeof(buf));
memset(args, '\0', sizeof(args));

printf("Type command: ");
fgets(buf, 500, stdin);
buf[(strlen(buf)-1)] = '\0'; //Did this to change newline character to null terminator.


printf("You typed: %s\n", buf);

args[0] = PATH;
args[1] = buf;

printf("PATH %s\n", PATH); //prints: ls
printf("buf: %s\n", buf); //prints: ls -pla
printf("args[0]: %s\n", args[0]); //prints ls
printf("args[1]: %s\n", args[1]); //prints ls -pla
printf("*args: %s\n", *args); //prints ls



//The below function registers the first argument and the 
//terminal behaves as if I had typed 'ls'.  
//But the second argument is not going through.
//What am I doing wrong?
    execlp(args[0], args[1], NULL);
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21558937/i-do-not-understand-how-execlp-works-in-linux

Comment: In addition to the link from @Mat that should help you with `execlp` you have another issue:  `char PATH[2] = "ls";` does not result in a valid string in `PATH` as there is not enough room for the terminating NUL. Increase the array size by 1.

Comment: Also the NULL must be cast to (const char*) as per the Linux manualst